# php returning excel file from server, that i dont want to

Tags: php

i have file called Admission.xls in my server
i want to write $_POST data in that file & save it in the server only, i dont to return to the user, but it returning to user

Here is my code

```
<?php 

// ----- begin of function library ----- 
// Excel begin of file header 
function xlsBOF() { 
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);  
    return; 
    } 
// Excel end of file footer 
function xlsEOF() { 
    echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00); 
    return; 
} 
// Function to write a Number (double) into Row, Col 
function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) { 
    echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0); 
    echo pack("d", $Value); 
    return; 
} 
// Function to write a label (text) into Row, Col 
function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value ) { 
    $L = strlen($Value); 
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
    echo $Value; 
return; 
} 
// ----- end of function library -----

// ------ MS EXCEL START ------

header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");     
header ("Pragma: no-cache");     
header ('Content-type: application/x-msexcel'); 
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Admission.xls" );  
header ("Content-Description: PHP/INTERBASE Generated Data" );

// -----LOOP $_POST VALUES -----
$row = 2;
$col = 1;
xlsBOF();
foreach($_POST as $value ) {
    xlsWriteLabel($row, $col, $value );
    $col++;
}
xlsEOF();

// ------ MS EXCEL END -----
?>
```

if possible please tell me how to open, write and save excel file that is in server
THANK you

Comment: Set output buffering before the foreach, read the output buffer to a variable and write that variable to a file after the foreach, and don't send the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use PHPExcel, you will be having lots of methods to achieve this task.

[Have look here](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Post code, or an example, not just the link because it can go dead and your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by capturing the output buffer and write it to a file.

Read up on this here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

---

This how you do it in your script.

Remove these:

```
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");     
header ("Pragma: no-cache");     
header ('Content-type: application/x-msexcel'); 
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Admission.xls" );  
header ("Content-Description: PHP/INTERBASE Generated Data" );
```

And change your `foreach` loop code like this:

```
// -----LOOP $_POST VALUES -----
ob_start();
$row = 2;
$col = 1;
xlsBOF();
foreach($_POST as $value ) {
    xlsWriteLabel($row, $col, $value );
    $col++;
}
xlsEOF();
$xlsData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// -----WRITE EXCEL DATA TO FILE--
$h = @fopen('Admission.xls', 'w');
if ($h) {
    fwrite($h, $xlsData);
    fclose($h);
}

// -----
exit('Post data written to Admission.xls on server.');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kanes, but when i do it over and over the conent is replacing at the same row, i just want to append/ or add at new row

Actually i am doing online registration form for school, student details should save in the xls sheet, so each student data should save on that same file but it must not replace previous student data

Comment: Why aren't you storing the `data` in a `database`?

Comment: customer require data in the form of excel sheet

Comment: okay; but nothing is stopping you storing the data in a logical manner in the database and then provide an export functionality which reads data from db and save it into excel file per student basis.